# How to display a custom render element after an existing one?

Tags: theming, 8

So I've implemented `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view` hook.

In there I add a view mode to the `$build` array:

```
$build['sessions'] = array(
  [
    "#markup" => "<h2>Sessies</h2>",
    "content" => array(
      Drupal::entityManager()->getViewBuilder('node')->viewMultiple($nodes, 'speaker_sessions')
    )
  ]
);
```

What happends now is that this will allways be rendered before all the other content. How can I manipulate this? Adding `#weight` to this element does not seems to effect the other content.

Comment: What makes you think that it is *before*? You are doing it while the other node is being rendered, which means it obviously *finishes* first, as you are printing out it within its template and it has to render and display that as part of displaying the parent node. But that doesn't mean it's before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that code is correct?

```
$build['sessions'] = array(
  [
    "#markup" => "<h2>Sessies</h2>",
    "content" => array(
      Drupal::entityManager()->getViewBuilder('node')->viewMultiple($nodes, 'speaker_sessions')
    )
  ]
);
```

It appears you are creating 2 arrays (`array()` and `[]`). The given example [`hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view/8.2.x) looks like this:

```
$build['mymodule_addition'] = array(
  '#markup' => mymodule_addition($entity),
  '#theme' => 'mymodule_my_additional_field',
);
```

The problem you are likely having is because of the nested array. If you apply a weight to the inner array, it will sink to the bottom of the outer array. You however still have no control over the position of the outer array. So either use a single array and add the weight there, or use the double array as it is, but apply the weight to the outer array.

But that conflicts a bit with your question because this is not a view mode, it is just an extra render element.

Comment: Well, it works and prints out the template which I use for that view mode. I only have no control over the order. It's just another valid render array

Comment: Does it give you more control if you change it to the recommended format? If you add a weight within the second array, it will sink to the bottom of the first array (which only contains this item). So I recommend using one array and adding a weight there. Or if you insist on using this format, add the weight to the outer array.

Comment: Well, I dont need the second array. but I might add more in that later. If I just go `'content' => Drupal::entityManager()->getViewBuilder('node')->viewMultiple($nodes, 'speaker_sessions')`, it's the same thing. Tried it, but didn't change anything.

Comment: You are the boss ;) Did you read my updated suggestion about adding a weight on the outer array? If that does not solve it, I don't know either...

Comment: Shit, you were right. When trying your suggestion I made an error, which didnt result in an error. I indeed just used one array like this: `$build['sessions'] = array(
      "#markup" => "<h2>Sessies</h2>",
      "#weight" => 2,
      "content" => Drupal::entityManager()->getViewBuilder('node')->viewMultiple($nodes, 'speaker_sessions')
    );
` and the weight works.

Comment: I always am ;-) Good to hear you got this sorted!